# How can I revive a dead translation team?

Tags: launchpad, translation

I wish to translate ubuntu in Marathi language for which a translation team already exists. But the membership of the team is moderated and unfortunately no new member has been admitted in the team after 2010-Dec-12. All request of membership are pending after that date. I tried to contact administrator of the team at his personal email id but did not get any reply from him. As I am not a team member I can not upload my translated po file. Is there any way to take charge of the team and approve all pending request? It seems that no translation work is currently being carried out. I would like to do the work but I can not.

Here is the webpage of the team https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-mr see the number of approved and active members

Answer (score 3):

See the [Role Reassignment Policy](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations/KnowledgeBase/RoleReassignmentPolicy) of the [Ubuntu Translations Coordinators](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuTranslationsCoordinators)